# How to figure out number of atoms in a molecule? e.g. Phosphorus exists as P4

Tags: organic-chemistry

We know that Phosphorus exists as P4 but how can I figure out the number of atoms in a molecule for other elements?

[image: Question]

This is the question that requires the use of P4. I would never have known Phosphorus is tetra-atomic and that the equation will involve this. Is there a way to figure that out?

Comment: Welcome to ChemSE.  Please familiarize yourself with how the site works, i.e. show initial effort by you to solve the question by your own, and try to formulate the questions specifically.  For your quesion here: among the references consulted, did you throw an eye on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elemental_analysis?

Comment: Hint: Molecular weight.

Comment: I've updated the question, my apologies.

Comment: Not better. If you have no idea about this, why do you want to write an exam? First study, the aim for a certificate.

Comment: What are you talking about? I can write the equation successfully with the knowledge that Phosphorus is P4 but I want to know how or why that's the case. Also, let's assume the question asked 'Bromine reacts with Sulfur to form...', how would I figure out the formula of Sulfur?

Comment: If the question is "how do I find out" the answer is: look it up in a book. If the question is "how did chemists work out the formulae in the first place" then answer is a lot more interesting and complicated (after all, it took a long time).

Comment: Most probably the question is targeting basic lexical knowledge / counting electrons, making lewis structures, applying VSEPR.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are asking how to identify the standard state chemical structure of an element; this is obtained from empirical data.

The standard state is defined as the most stable allotrope of the element under standard conditions. For example, graphite is the standard state for carbon. Phosphorus, however, is an exception: while white phosphorus is not the most stable allotrope, it is the easiest to characterize, and is defined as the standard state for phosphorus.

The chemical formula for each element at standard conditions is that of the standard state. Except for the gases $\ce{H2, N2, O2, F2, Cl2, Br2, I2}$, and the solids $\ce{P4, S8}$, all other elements exist in monatomic form in the standard state.